# All Multisites are working as one site

Tags: multisite

I have installed wordpress multisite on my domain fashiontive.com, then I added a site which is ae.fashiontive.com . But ae.fashiontive.com is redirecting to the base site fashiontive.com .... Why?
Then I added a new site sa.fashiontive.com, then both of them sites are loading fine, but when I change a site's name from general settings, the changes take effect on both site.... When I upload a product on a site, It uploads on both site, anything I change on one site, it takes effect to both site.
And most strange thing is that, if I go to to permalink of sa.fashiontive.com, from settings, I can see that the permalinks are ae.fashiontive.com, how it could be???

All I have in my .httaccess file is this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

which I got from my main network site during install, I also put some codes on wp config which was told me during multisite installation as usual....

So please help me, I didn't any solution online....

Comment: Was the site originally set up as MultiSite, or did you convert it from a single site? Have you set up the subdomains with your registrar (not just in WP)?

Comment: Yes sir, I created subdomains, but yes, I was using a single site before, then recently I enabled multi-site on the site I was running

Comment: Converting sites is not always a clean process. It may help to set up a brand-new MultiSite install and import your content.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/299225/edit) to add the code you added to `wp-config.php` (just the Multisite-related `define()` items; **do not** post any passwords on this site).